# Access-Control-Expose-Headers does not work to allow JS client side to read cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies, cors, httpresponse, credentials

I make AJAX calls to CORS server, I make many attempts to be able to read cookies returned on response using javascript client side, however, in vain .

## 1. First Attempt :

### - Server Side (node.js powered by express) :

```
  response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept, Set-Cookie');
  response.header('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', "Set-Cookie");

 //------SET COOKIES
  response.cookie('SessionId', GeneratorId(64), {
            maxAge:3600000,
            httpOnly:flase // i disable httpOnly ==> does not work
          });
```

### - client Side :

```
var xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost:9090/api/map", true);
xhttp,send(`{layer:1}`);
```

## 2. Second Attempt: (withCredentials)

### -Server Side :

```
 //Append another response' header 
  response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials','true');
```

### -Client Side :

```
// Before xhttp.send , I add another instruction : 
 xhttp.withCredentials=true;
```

## 3. Third Attempt :

### - Server Side :

```
//Avoid the wildcard on Access-Control-Allow-Origin =>Replace the first header by :
response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', request.get('Origin'));
```

### - Client Side :

```
 // Nothing is appended
```

---

## Conclusion :

With all those attempts , `xhttp.getResponseHeader('Set-Cookie')` still returns `null` even :

- `Set-Cookie` is assigned  to the response header : `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` .
- I saw cookies on the browser console (Inspector) :

[image]

Comment: `xhttp.withCredentials();` is not a function ... your browsers developer tools console would've shown this error ... try `xhttp.withCredentials=true;`

Comment: This is miss-priny, i update it ... thank you anyway

Answer (score 16, accepted):

TL;DR: the `Set-Cookie` header is entirely off-limits: you can't access it, even when you include it in `Access-Control-Expose-Headers`. However, once it's set, and the cookie isn't marked `httpOnly`, you should be able to access it through [`document.cookie`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie).

TMI follows:

As documented [here](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-response-cors-exposed-header-name-list),

> A response will typically get its CORS-exposed header-name list set by parsing the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header. This list is used by a *CORS filtered response* to determine which headers to expose.

What a *CORS filtered response* is, is documented [here](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-filtered-response-cors):

> A CORS filtered response is a filtered response whose type is "cors", header list excludes any headers in internal response's header list whose name is not a CORS-safelisted response-header name, given internal response's CORS-exposed header-name list, and trailer is empty.

And safelisted headers are subsequently documented [here](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-safelisted-response-header-name):

> - `Cache-Control`
> - `Content-Language`
> - `Content-Type`
> - `Expires`
> - `Last-Modified`
> - `Pragma`
>
> Any value in list that is not a forbidden response-header name.

Finally, the list of forbidden response-header names is listed [here](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-response-header-name):

> - `Set-Cookie`
> - `Set-Cookie2`

Comment: RESOLVED, by `withCredentials` also .

Comment: Somehow I cannot access the cookie via `document.cookie`, though I can see it being sent in subsequent ajax requests to my backand REST API server. The response setting the cookie has a header of `Set-Cookie: session_id=7; SameSite=None; Secure`, no `HttpOnly` flag.